# A word that fits in three sentences

Tags: word-request

I have an exercise in which I am asked to fill one word to three different sentences. And I am completely helpless with the following three sentences:

1. I swear I'll never let you get away with it. You can be sure one day you'll ______ for all your crooked ways.
2. Where are your manners? Don't ____ me back, you rude boy
3. Can you ____ the door? I'm having a shower.

The word needs to be exactly the same in all three sentences.

Comment: When asking questions like this, please tell us what words you thought matched at least one of the examples, and why you thought they did not match all of the examples.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The answer is the verb *answer*.